# Выполнение определенного кода в C

Tags: c

Можно ли с помощью стандартных библиотек языка или препроцессора выполнять код с определенного места? Т.е работа программы закончилась на 10 строке, а затем начать выполнять программу с 3 строки кода? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Операторы условного перехода, в крайнем случае `goto` - не подходят?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setjmp.h

Comment: При нормальном структурно-ориентированном (как минимум) подходе для этой цели используются циклические конструкции (`while`, `for`).

Comment: Если использовать цикл поверх `switch` - то можно выполнять произвольный переход на метки.

Comment: Вопрос непонятен. Что значит **работа программы закончилась на 10 строке** ?  Там у вас стоит *return* или *exit(0)* ? 


Что значит **начать выполнять программу** ?  На выполнение Вашу программу запускает ОС. Что Вы о неё хотите? Она всегда запускает программу на выполенеие, передавая управление в точку входа функции *main()*. И никуда более... Объясните толком, чего Вы хотите ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Либо использовать `goto lable` (что, вообще говоря, не очень рекомендуется) либо как-то иначе зациклить код, например, используя циклы `for`, `while`, `do while`. Полагаю здесь лучше подойдет `do while`, так как вне зависимости от условия Вы попадете в тело цикла.